# « Sec » ou « à sec »

Tags: sens, prépositions, adjectifs

La page 123 de *Advanced French Grammar* de Véronique Mazet présente ce qui suit :

> La rivière le long de laquelle je me promène est presque **à sec**. = The river along which I am walking is almost dry.

**Question 1.** Pourquoi la phrase emploie-t-elle « à sec » au lieu de simplement « sec » ?

Peut-on la réécrire ainsi :

> La rivière le long de laquelle je me promène est presque **sèche**.

**Question 2.** Y a-t-il d'autres adjectifs qui doivent être précédés par le pronom *à* ?

---

**Un supplément suite à la réponse de Valram**

Je vous remercie de votre réponse, grâce à laquelle j'ai corrigé *sec* en *sèche*. Puisque la réponse à ma deuxième question est affirmative, je voudrais la généraliser : quelle est la différence entre *à + adj.* et *adj.* dans le cas général ?

D'après votre explication — utile — de
*à sec* vs. *sec* et de *à vide* vs. *vide*,
je me doute que si une étendue d'eau est à sec, le sens sera vraiment que l'étendue d'eau est vide.

Ainsi, est-il correct de généraliser en disant que *à + adj.* est l'adjectif au sens figuré et non pas littéral? 
Y a-t-il d'autres différences ou nuances en général ?

Comment: Si j'avais un adjectif à utiliser pour remplacer _à sec_ dans cette phrase, je choisirais plutôt _asséchée_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Réponse suite au supplément de question :**

Le mot "sec" dans la proposition "la rivière est à sec" n'est pas au sens figuré, puisque la rivière est littéralement asséchée. Le sens figuré du mot "sec" serait par exemple pour le ton d'une phrase :

> il m'a parlé d'un ton **sec**.

Je dirais donc qu'il n'est pas correct de généraliser ainsi.

D'autres exemples d'adjectifs pouvant s'utiliser avec un *à* :

- **à chaud** : "sur le moment" (on peut donner son impression à chaud sur un
  évènement)

  - Peut aussi avoir le sens plus littéral de procéder à une opération quand le matériau est chaud (un rivetage à chaud)
- **à froid** : le contraire d'*à chaud*, on attend d'avoir pris
  du recul
- **à plein** : "entièrement", sûrement un raccourci d'*à plein
  régime*

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 11):

Une remarque préliminaire « rivière » étant un nom féminin on accorde « sec » qui donne « sèche », « à sec » lui ne s'accordant pas.

**Question 1.**

Non, on ne peut pas remplacer « à sec » par « sèche ». Leurs emplois ne sont pas interchangeables.

On emploie « à sec » dans le cas où l'on décrit la situation de quelque chose qui est censé être composé d'eau, mais dans lequel justement il n'y a plus d'eau. Une mare, un étang, un océan, une rivière ou un fleuve, par exemple, peuvent être « à sec ».

En revanche l'emploi de « sec » se fait dans le cas d'une chose qui est peu humide, dont une partie de l'eau qui la composait a disparu. Un terrain peut être « sec » par opposition à  « humide », la peau peut être « sèche » par opposition à « hydratée ».

**Question 2.**

Il existe aussi une expression similaire avec l'adjectif  « vide ».

> Le moteur tourne **à vide**. *The engine runs idle.*

En revanche pour un contenant « vide » s'emploie seul.

> Le sac est **vide**. *The bag is empty*

Comme autres exemples je pense également à « plein », « chaud » et « froid ».

**Supplément**

Non, *à + adj.* n'implique pas qu'il s'agit d'un sens figuré.

Dans le cas de la rivière, « à sec » est employé au sens propre. Par contre dans l'expression « être à sec » (*to be broke*), « à sec » est employé au sens figuré.

De même l'adjectif seul, sans le « à », peut être employé au sens propre, « un fruit sec », ou figuré, « un coup sec ».

Comment: L'expression « à vide » ici, n'est-elle pas un adverbe ? On peut dire « le moteur tourne *comment* ? » - « à vide ». Mais dans la phrase avec la rivière on ne peut pas faire ça.

Comment: @Valram: Merci beaucoup de votre réponse. SVP, puis-je diriger votre attention sur un supplément avec lequel j'ai mis à jour mon poste original ? Artyom, je m'y intéresse aussi.

Comment: @Valram: Merci beaucoup. Je trouve votre réponse fortement utile, après laquelle Trajan a repliqué au supplément. Malheureusement, ce site Web ne permet d'accepter qu'une réponse. Toutefois, j'ai voté pour la vôtre mais veuillez m'excuser.