# What is the sense in which “à” is used in “à haut débit”?

Tags: sens, prépositions

In the phrase

> Une connexion Internet à haut débit

What is the sense in which *à* is used?

I tried to look up [its definition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0), but given that it is full of technical terms, I was only able to shortlist the following. I have still not been able to determine exactly. In the À+adj. case *haut* is not in the list so I was not sure.

- C.− À entre dans la construction d'une locution verbale
- F.− [À introduit un complément circonstanciel de manière, de matière,
  d'indice, de cause, de moyen, etc.]
- À + adj. : à bas (jeter, mettre) à blanc (chauffer, tirer) à chaud
  (opérer) à cru (monter) à faux (porter) à froid (opérer, traiter) à jeun
  (être, rester) à neuf (mettre, remettre) à nu (être, mettre) à plat
  (être, mettre, tomber) à plein (fonctionner, tourner) à ras (couper) à
  sec (être, mettre) à vide (tourner, revenir) à vif (être, mettre)
- B.− Le substantif déterminé par le complément introduit par à est un
  substantif qui entre dans une locution verbale suivie de à
- À introduit un compl. indiquant le moyen par lequel fonctionne un
  instrument, un appareil ... (à + subst. non actualisé)

---

Also, could you help me understand the following phrase:

> Photocopier grâce à une photocopieuse

Both the sense of à and the meaning of "grâce".

Comment: These two uses of *à* are quite unrelated; “grâce à” is a set locution.

Comment: Il vous sera utile de vous référer à ma question: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6692/sec-ou-a-sec?rq=1.

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence, *à* can be replaced by *avec*:

> Une connexion Internet avec un haut débit

---

The other sentence

> Photocopier grâce à une photocopieuse

Could be reworded as:

> Photocopier "en utilisant" une photocopieuse.

But it's really a pleonasm.

Comment: Thanks M42, could you also point out the correct usage of à from the list? Or is there some other sense which I miss? I guess it's the last one?

Comment: Did not understand your second rewording, sorry M42. What does it mean?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: literaly "Photocopy using a photocopier".

Comment: thanks. So 'grâce' is a noun or verb?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: It's a noun.